# What does $\langle\overline{4}\rangle$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

What does $\langle\overline{4}\rangle$ mean?

Context: Find the right cosets of $H<G$ and $[G:H]$ where $G=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and $H=\langle\overline{4}\rangle$

Comment: H is the group generated by $4\in \mathbb Z_{12}, $ modulo $12$.

Comment: @amWhy What is the difference between $\langle 4 \rangle$ and $\langle \overline{4} \rangle?$

Comment: Technically, the elements of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ under modulo arithmetic are the equivalence classes: $\{\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2, \ldots, \bar {10,} \bar {11}\}$.  More casually, we refer to the group elements by the least non-negative integer representing their equivalence class.

Comment: If you were working in $\mathbb{Z}$ only, then $\langle{4}\rangle$ would be the set $\{...,-8,-4,0,4,8,...\}$.

Comment: @amWhy I "think" I see it. Would it be right to say that $gH$ is $\{ \overline{4}, \overline{8}, \overline{12}, \overline{11\cdot4} \dots \overline{12}\dots \overline{11\cdot12} \}$?

Comment: You have to be careful.  The operation you are using determines if it is a group.  for example, if $H=\langle \overline{4} \rangle=\{\overline{0}, \overline{4}, \overline{8}\}$, then since you are using addition modulo $12$, then $\overline{2}H=\{\overline{2}, \overline{6},\overline{10}\}.$

Comment: Also note that $gH$ are left cosets.  $Hg$ are right cosets.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven But does it matter in this particular case? If the group operation is commutative, is $gH = Hg$?

Comment: @Cure, you are correct.  I just wanted to point in out just in case the OP was unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\bar{4}=\{4+12k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is an element of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ and so $\langle \bar{4}\rangle$ is the subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ generated by $\bar{4}$; that is, the group of all powers of $\bar{4}$ in $\Bbb Z_{12}$, which, since the operation is additive, are all multiples of $\bar{4}$.